# What is the proper way to handle periodic housekeeping tasks in Python/Pyramid/CherryPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, cherrypy

I have a python web-app that uses Pyramid/CherryPy for the webserver.

It has a few periodic housekeeping tasks that need to be run - Clearing out stale sessions, freeing their resources, etc...

What is the proper way to manage this? I can fairly easily just run a additional "housekeeping" thread (and use a separate scheduler, like [APscheduler](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/)), but having a separate thread reach into the running server thread(s) just seems like a really clumsy solution. CherryPy is already running the server in a (multi-threaded) eventloop, it seems like it should be possible to somehow schedule periodic events through that.

Comment: Which platform does the web-app run?

Comment: @mskimm - Can you be more specific? It's Python3+CherryPy+Pyramid+mako (for templates), all on linux. It's hosted on a box I control, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the "main" channel at http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/progguide/extending/customplugins.html

Comment: Bingo. That looks almost exactly what I want. Let me have a poke at implementing something, and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Actually, reading the documentation on the plugin interface lead me to the ["BackgroundTask"](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/refman/process/plugins/#cherrypy.process.plugins.BackgroundTask) plugin, which is *literally* exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The link is dead. What do I do now?

Comment: @FakeName Your link is also dead

Comment: @Ajoy - New link: http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.process.html?highlight=backgroundtask#cherrypy.process.plugins.BackgroundTask

Comment: It looks like readthedocs breaks all the old links every time the API gets updated to any substantial extent.

Answer (score 2):

I was lead to this answer by @fumanchu's answer, but I wound up using an instance of the [`cherrypy.process.plugins.BackgroundTask`](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.process.html?highlight=backgroundtask#cherrypy.process.plugins.BackgroundTask) plugin:

```
def doHousekeeping():
    print("Housekeeper!")
```

-

```
def runServer():


    cherrypy.tree.graft(wsgi_server.app, "/")

    # Unsubscribe the default server
    cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()

    # Instantiate a new server object
    server = cherrypy._cpserver.Server()

    # Configure the server object
    server.socket_host = "0.0.0.0"
    server.socket_port = 8080
    server.thread_pool = 30

    # Subscribe this server
    server.subscribe()

    cherrypy.engine.housekeeper = cherrypy.process.plugins.BackgroundTask(2, doHousekeeping)
    cherrypy.engine.housekeeper.start()

    # Start the server engine (Option 1 *and* 2)
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Results in `doHousekeeping()` being called at 2 second intervals within the CherryPy event loop.

It also doesn't involve doing something as silly as dragging in the entire OS just to call a task periodically.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favour and just use cron. No need to roll your own scheduling software.

Comment: I agree as well. There's also a python package [python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/1.7.2) that let's you manage cron jobs from within Python.

Comment: When I say housekeeping, I mean internally within the application. Using cron and adding a dependency on the OS to manage that kind of thing seems insane to me. If I wanted to use a separate scheduler, I'd add a thread running something like [APscheduler](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/), which I'm already actually using elsewhere in the application. However, any such solution (basically relying on a external mechanism to intervene) seems overly complex and silly. CherryPy has an event-loop, there should be ways to queue events somehow.